# Chrome Extension failed with chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow 'Authorization page could not be loaded.'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to authorize with Google after start extension.

I write manifest.json and background.js as below.

**current directory structure**

[image: current directory structure]

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "***************",
  "short_name": "DSBOT",
  "version": "0.0.1.0",
  "description": "**************************",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon_16.png",
    "48": "images/icon_48.png",
    "128": "images/icon_128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/icon_19.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "storage"
  ],
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": **************,
    "scopes": ["openid", "email", "profile"],
    "hd": "zabuton.co.jp"
  }
}
```

**background.js**

```
var clientId = "********************";
var redirectURL = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL();
var url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?" +
  "scope=email&" +
  "response_type=token&" +
  "client_id=" + encodeURIComponent(clientId) + "&" +
  "redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(redirectURL) + "&" +
  "prompt=consent";;

chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({ url: url, interactive: true }, function(redirect_url) {
  console.log('redirect_url = ' + redirect_url);

  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
  }
});
```

After install and run, output log 'Authorization page could not be loaded.'.

`redirect_url` inside of `launchWebAuthFlow` is undefined.

If you know my mistake, please teach me.

Comment: Are you sure the site is not blocked? In other words do you see the network request being sent and a response received in devtools Network panel or in a standalone traffic sniffer like Fiddler, WireShark etc.?

Answer (score 5):

You don't have [the `key`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key) in your manifest.

You need to [copy your extension's key](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity#copy_key) to the manifest.

> When you register your application in the Google OAuth console, you'll
>   provide your application's ID, which will be checked during token
>   requests. Therefore it's important to have a consistent application ID
>   during development.
>
> To keep your application ID constant, you need to copy the key in the
>   installed manifest.json to your source manifest.

Comment: consent screen appear and instantly disappear and background js has error Authorization page could not be loaded. I have entered key correctly, its working on my pc but not working in anyother pc? any idea

Comment: FIXED: If youtube is blocked at your network, you will get error Authorization page could not be loaded.