# Auth0 Universal Login in a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, auth0, browser-extension, webauthn

I'm trying to use the [`auth0-chrome`](https://github.com/auth0-community/auth0-chrome) package to authenticate my users. I've followed their "Using the Library" section (set up a new native type application in my tenant and configured the **Allowed Callback URLs** and **Allowed Origins**). When emitting my `authenticate` event to my background script and calling the `authenticate()` method on the new `Auth0Chrome` instance, I get the error

```
Authorization page could not be loaded
```

My current theory is that since the allowed origin's format in the example is `https://<extension-id>.chromiumapps.org` and I can't currently access that page. Is there a certain visibility level for a Chrome extension to have a valid URL (e.g. atm for a privately published extension, the `*.chromiumapp.org` URL is invalid).

I thought a code example is not needed, since I'm literally using the default example's code with my extension ID replaced.

I have double checked and my ID is the same for the auth0 application config, my unpacked extension in my browser and for the configured code. I'm using a manifest key to persist the extension ID if that's of any value.

Comment: Have you checked if the site is not blocked? Also, have you checked [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44017814/chrome-extension-failed-with-chrome-identity-launchwebauthflow-authorization-pa)?

Comment: The post suggests using the `key` field in the manifest to persist the extension ID, which I'm doing. I'm not sure I quite understand by a site being blocked? Do you mean by my local network? That shouldn't be the case. I guess I'll try a workaround with redirecting to the extension schema and into my options page, e.g. `chrome-extension://<id>/options.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the documentation lists the callback url example as `https://<yourchromeappid>.chromiumapps.org/auth0`, but it should be `https://<yourchromeappid>.chromiumapp.org/auth0` - without the `s` at the end of `chromiumapp`.

That was the only change required to making it work. I've proposed an update for their documentation as well.